# Creating a fast dictionary

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, dictionary, graph

For a school task I have to create a graph and do some stuff with it. In input each vertex has an ID that is a number 0-999'999'999. As I can not create an array this long, I can't really use this ID as a key in adjacency matrix.
My first solution was to create a separate ID that is arbitrary of the original one and store it in some kind of dictionary/map thing, but as I get 10'000 records of vertices the lookup is probably bound to get slow. The algorithm has to be under O(n^2) and I already have a BFS and a toposort in there.
What would be the best solution in this case? As a side note - I can't use already established libraries (so I can't use graph, map, vector, string classes etc.), but I can code them myself, if that is the best option.

Comment: seems to me like the assignment is there to teach you about these datastructures by building them yourself. Have you learned about hash tables? AVL/Red-Black trees?

Comment: No we haven't learned about hash tables, but it is not the point of the assignment. The theme for this is Graphs (toposort, BFS, DFS, DAGs etc).
I could make a binary tree for lookup, but I am just wondering if that is the best solution (seems overly complex)

Comment: If your array is ordered by ID, then it is much faster to look for specific IDs (hint: start checking the ID value in the middle cell f the array)

Comment: @vvolis What you want is a binary search tree to do lookups in `O(logn)` time or a hash map to do lookups in `~O(1)` time. As @amit told you, check AVL/Red-Black trees and hash maps. There's no better way to do lookups in a graph below `O(n)` unless you can change the topology of the graph to turn it into a "search graph".

Comment: Thank you @mostruash, this is exactly the answer I was looking for!  Can you please post it as answer so I can mark this as solved? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a binary search tree to do lookups in `O(logn)` time or a hash map to do lookups in `~O(1)` time OR you can go with the array route in which case the size of your array would be the max value your ID can have (in your case, `10^9`).

As @amit told you, check AVL/Red-Black trees and hash maps. There's no better way to do lookups in a graph below `O(n)` unless you can change the topology of the graph to turn it into a "search graph".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create an array of size 1 billion. You can simply create and adjacency matrix or adjacency list of number of nodes.

Whether number of vertices are constant or not, I'd suggest you to go for [adjacency list](https://www.google.com/search?q=adjacency%20list&safe=off&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&imgil=xgKi-JDKxlIzYM%253A%253BbS8iZppGtEtgRM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.bytehood.com%25252Fgraph-algorithms-part-i%25252F258%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=xgKi-JDKxlIzYM%253A%252CbS8iZppGtEtgRM%252C_&usg=__sig7K9VyP2UwSxIkFIBugKIhSKs%3D&biw=1366&bih=653&ved=0CDsQyjc&ei=0M1pVPy1KoSvygO-w4GoCw#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=xgKi-JDKxlIzYM%253A%3BbS8iZppGtEtgRM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bytehood.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F01%252Fadjaceny-list.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bytehood.com%252Fgraph-algorithms-part-i%252F258%252F%3B272%3B132). For example, you have 10 nodes,so you need to create an array of size 10, then for each nodes create a list of edges as you can see in the link above.

[image: graph]

Consider this graph, do you really think you need to have 10^10 element in the adjacency list instead of 4 elements?

Comment: The problem is that if I have 10 vertices, in array their IDs are 1-10, but in each vertex its adjacent units are shown as e.g. 89777371 and 13876873 which I have to translate to 1-10. For each vertex this takes up time. Whith an array of size 1 billion I would immediately know where the specific vertex is.

Comment: Why if the name of the vertices were 10 digit string? Do you need to use 26^10 rows for matrix? Each node adjacency list has `value` and `next`, inside value you will say `89777371` and the value of the next element will be `13876873`, so there is no need for mapping.

Comment: They are not in an ordered list. Therefore upon each vertex I have to lookup their adjacent vertexes through a map. I see that the next node is e.g. 36827648736 but I have no idea which of the 10 elements in my array that one is.

Comment: I added graph. If you want to create a list of 10^10 for this graph, I don't know a solution for that.